# Redirect rest endpoints to webapp S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have s3 serving my React App.  Whats the best way to redirect any requests that have /api in the url to my webserver.  Currently my CORS config in S3 redirects GET only and I know this is not the correct way to handle api endpoints. 

`somedomain.com -> serve static s3 react app
somedomain.com/api -> send requests to webapp (hosted at api.somedomain.com)`

My other option is to just let nginx handle serving the app and api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cloud Front and Change the incoming patterns to different origin.

Answer (score 0):

A static website hosted on Bitbucket will only allow (and redirect) GET requests.

I'd recommend you set the `api.somedomain.com` as your api endpoint in your JS. This would avoid the need for the `/api` route.

Comment: Yea the only the company wants to maintain some backwards compatibility with existing routes.  For now I will just proxy everything thru nginx and mess around with AWS to see whats possible.

Comment: If you are open to the extra cost (with the benefit of faster downloads from s3), checkout AWS Cloudfront or Cloudflare.com

Comment: Thanks I'm testing CloudFront out now.  Doesn't seem like it'll be much of a cost for us anyways.